# Jquery 1.3.2 compatible plugin not working with Jquery 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, performance, upgrade

I have a site running in the client's production server. On the home page, there is one slider which was created using the jQuery version 1.3.2 (as the site was created before few years). Now as there will be a compatibility issue with Microsoft's upcoming Internet Explorer version I have to update the jQuery version higher than 1.6. I removed the old jQuery code and placed the code of jQuery v1.7.1 but the slider stops working on the home page. As it is already deployed site I am not able to replace the entire slider.

Is there any work around to upgrade the jQuery from v1.3.2 to v1.7.1?

Comment: Why don't you use the latest version of plugin

Comment: As the client's site is running in production server and the designing of pages are already done. So I was thinking to upgrade the jQuery without developing new one with lesser downtime.

Comment: Will it be possible for me to do without developing new one? @Tushar